# Asterisk: forward if peer unreachable

Tags: asterisk

I would like to respond to incoming calls by checking if a specific peer is reachable, and dial the appropriate number accordingly.

Presently I did this:

```
exten => 1200,1,Answer()
same => n,Set(reachable=${SHELL(asterisk -rx "sip show peers" | grep ^cedrich-phone.*OK)})
same => n,GotoIf($["${LEN(${reachable})}" = "0"]?extoffline)
same => n,Dial(SIP/cedrich-phone,20)
same => n(extoffline),Dial(SIP/another-phone,20,tr)
same => n,Hangup()
```

Could you tell me if this is acceptable and if it can be improved by using the best practices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Executing a shell of asterisk on an incoming call just doesn't feel right to me. It probably works ok but shouldn't the status of a peer be already known to asterisk?

I use the function [`SIPPEER()`](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+func+sippeer) with which you can request the status of a peer. If the first 3 characters (of `OK (44 ms)`) is `OK` then you can call the peer. All other situations you can forward to another peer.

I do something like this:

```
exten => _202,1,Log(NOTICE,Dial Status of ${EXTEN}: ${SIPPEER(${EXTEN},status)})
exten => _202,n,GotoIf($["${SIPPEER(${EXTEN},status):0:3}"="OK "]?ok1:forward)
exten => _202,n(ok1),Log(NOTICE,Calling number is available)
exten => _202,n,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN},50,wW)
exten => _202,n,Hangup()
exten => _202,n(forward),Log(NOTICE,Calling forward number)
exten => _202,n,Dial(SIP/201,50,wW)
exten => _202,n,Hangup()
```

This checks the status before we're going to `Dial()` and goes to `n(forward)` if the peer is unavailable, busy or otherwise not OK.

There is however a small problem with this. When the peer denies the call (or is for another reason unavailable, e.g. he went online before our next online-check) the call doesn't get through.

There is a function [`DIALSTATUS`](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+variable+DIALSTATUS) we can use after the `Dial()` to check if the call was answered succefully. So use this after the `Dial()` and if it's not answered also do the forward. (It worked in a test i did. Denying the call gave `BUSY` in the log and went to the next peer)

You get something like this:

```
exten => _202,1,Log(NOTICE,Dial Status of ${EXTEN}: ${SIPPEER(${EXTEN},status)})
exten => _202,n,GotoIf($["${SIPPEER(${EXTEN},status):0:3}"="OK "]?ok1:forward)
exten => _202,n(ok1),Log(NOTICE,Calling number is available)
exten => _202,n,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN},50,wW)
exten => _202,n,Log(NOTICE,Dial status: ${DIALSTATUS})
exten => _202,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS)}"="ANSWER"]?ok2:forward)
exten => _202,n(ok2),Log(NOTICE,Successfull call)
exten => _202,n,Hangup()
exten => _202,n(forward),Log(NOTICE,Calling forward number)
exten => _202,n,Dial(SIP/201,50,wW)
exten => _202,n,Hangup()
```

I didn't test this last bit (with `DIALSTATUS`) extensively so you should do some test but here it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

As @arheops mentioned, you can use DEVICE_STATE() to get the status of a specific device, if it's 1:1 mapping (1 account on 1 device). You can use the following:

```
${DEVICE_STATE(${CHANNEL(channeltype)}/${CHANNEL(peername)})}
```

Another possibility is EXTENSION_STATE() function in case you have 1:many mapping (one extension with more than one device).

Both can have hints as described [here](http://www.asteriskdocs.org/en/3rd_Edition/asterisk-book-html-chunk/DeviceStates_id265377.html) if you need to have one user to use multiple devices. [Here](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+standard+extensions) you can see how to make dynamic hints

Answer (score -1):

Use of system in dialplan will open shell and spawn 2 proccess for each call.

Sure asterisk have function for your task. It described in all books.

```
-= Info about function 'DEVICE_STATE' =- 

[Synopsis]
Get or Set a device state. 

[Description]
The DEVICE_STATE function can be used to retrieve the device state from any
device state provider. For example:
NoOp(SIP/mypeer has state ${DEVICE_STATE(SIP/mypeer)})
NoOp(Conference number 1234 has state ${DEVICE_STATE(MeetMe:1234)})
The DEVICE_STATE function can also be used to set custom device state from
the dialplan.  The 'Custom:' prefix must be used. For example:
Set(DEVICE_STATE(Custom:lamp1)=BUSY)
Set(DEVICE_STATE(Custom:lamp2)=NOT_INUSE)
You can subscribe to the status of a custom device state using a hint in
the dialplan:
exten => 1234,hint,Custom:lamp1
The possible values for both uses of this function are:
UNKNOWN | NOT_INUSE | INUSE | BUSY | INVALID | UNAVAILABLE | RINGING |
RINGINUSE | ONHOLD
```

Comment: I'd be happy to upvote your answer or even accept it if you could remove your useless first sentence and if you could expend your answer, not just copy pasting...

Comment: I am ok if you not upvote it. I am sorry, it is not clear what exactly i have expand. IF you need more info, you always can search by info provided, for example read this page http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+func+device_State. Or install freepbx and check it dialplan.